# what is the probability that the determinant of a matrix of order 2 is positive ,whose elements are i.u. ran.var.in the interval(0,1)?

Tags: probability

I have been thinking about the problem for quite a while and  it seems  to me a problem on geometric probability albeit in four dimensions.For if the elements of the matrix are a,b,c,d(row-wise) the value of the determinant is ad-bc.the problem reduces to finding the probability P(ad-bc>0) subject to given domain and distributation  of a,b,c,d.In our problem the sample space is the 4D  unit cube.If we take the axes as X,Y,Z,U THE REQUISITE PROBABILITY IS  GIVEN  BY THE FRACTION OF  4D VOLUME OF THE UNIT CUBE FOR WHICH XY-ZU>0.I would love to see a solution along these goemetrical lines

Answer (score 3):

The probability that the determinant is $0$ is $0$. Thus by symmetry the required probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Using arguments based on symmetry in case of a composite  function of uniform and independent variates can be erroneous.So the argument does not convince me evn though your answer can be correct

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the way a, b, c and d are distributed.

And please do not tell me they are uniformly distributed unless you give me finite bounds for them.

Comment: the bounds are given -they are 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

The products $ad$ and $bc$ have identical distributions, and $ad-bc$ is the convolution of the density distributions of $ad$ and $-bc$, which is symmetrical and centered at zero. So the probability is $1/2$.

Edit: that under the hypothesis that $a,b,c,d$ have the same density distribution.